# simple ruby if and else csv parse

Tags: ruby, csv

Right now, the email sends if my report contains those conditions >0 and >9. How do I make an else statement that doesn't send the email if the conditions aren't satisfied ( if for eg "item1" column contains all 0's). Something like, if conditions satisfied, email to send ; else don't send.

```
 csv = CSV.parse(report, :headers => true, :converters => :all).select do |row|
        row['item1'] > 0 && row['item2'] >=9
      end

    csv.each do |row|
    email.Body +=(row['item1']. +  row['item2'].to_s)
    end

    email.Send
```

Comment: You need to show your attempt at adding an "else". Without that evidence it looks like you didn't try. Please read "[mcve]". Also, you need to practice safe-indenting as it'll help your future self understand and debug your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
should_send = true

csv = CSV.parse(report, headers: true, converters: :all).select do |row|
  should_send = false if CONDITION
  row['item1'] > 0 && row['item2'] >=9
end

if should_send
  email.Body += csv.map { |row| "#{row['item1']}#{row['item2']}" }.join
  email.Send
end
```

Comment: my condition is the >0 and >=9, so what does that 'if CONDITION' do? Is that a built in ruby?

Comment: No, it is not ruby internal. I meant you might put any condition you want there.

Comment: so I wan to set it to false if the entire 'item1' column is all 0. Then in that case, no need to send an email because no point since my condition is >0. how would I check the entire csv column

Comment: @encrypt if no rows satisfy your condition `>0` you will have an empty `csv`